# Есть ли какое-то название для танцовщиков-мужчин в балете?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли какое-то название для танцовщиков-мужчин в балете? Или только "Солист балета"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Танцовщик - вполне употребительно.

*ТАНЦОВЩИК, -а; м.
Артист балета. Замечательный, известный т. Т. средней руки. Готовиться быть танцовщиком. < Танцовщица, -ы; ж. Знаменитая т.*

(словарь Кузнецова)

Заметьте, употребимо не только в отношении солистов, но и "массовки".